# Programming Error at/ relation "project_app_category" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run "docker-compose up" and my django app is not seeing all my Database tables.
I have run migrations multiple times and i have also syncdb but it's all to no avail.
I am using PostgreSQL as my db and all the database tables exist in the DB.

This is my settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "Vendor",
        "USER" : "postgres",
        "PASSWORD" : "sangobiyi",
        "HOST" : "db",
        "POST" : "5432",
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'Vendor'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'sangobiyi'
      
  web:
    build: .
    image: temiloluwaelizabeth/vendor-business:v1.0.0
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/vendor_business
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile

```
FOM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.8

LABEL Name-code6 Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 8000

ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000
ENV USWGI_INI uswgi.information

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN chmod g+w /app

ADD requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Whenever i change the host to "localhost" in my settings.py file and run python manage.py runserver it works fine but when i change the host in my settings.py to "db" and run docker-compose up it throws the programming error.

i have tried multiple times to run migrations and everything has migrated